# Display custom tag in google maps infowindow angular2

Tags: google-maps, angular

map.component.ts code:

```
......
infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
{
    content: `<custom-tag></custom-tag>`    //***not displaying anything***
});
infoWindow.open(map, marker);
......
```

map.component.html code:

```
<custom-tag></custom-tag>      <!--***displays hi***-->
<div class="google-maps"></div>
```

custom-tag.component.html code:

```
<h2>hi</h2>
```

The module.ts, routing.ts files have no errors for sure.
The infowindow just opens and displays nothing,
Please help me in figuring out why the infowindow is not displaying anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to create component dynamically via `ComponentFactoryResolver`

```
const compFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(CustomTag);
this.compRef = compFactory.create(this.injector);

this.appRef.attachView(this.compRef.hostView);

let div = document.createElement('div');
div.appendChild(this.compRef.location.nativeElement);

this.infoWindow.setContent(div);
this.infoWindow.open(this.map, marker);
```

Here is **[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/MG8NPzyddOJ4oMltTPxf?p=preview)**

Don't forget to add `CustomTag` component to `entryComponents`