# Insert dynamic Angular 4.x content with known/declared components

Tags: angular, typescript, dynamic-content

I have a (what I think would be a fairly common) problem that I cannot find a good way to solve with the current Angular 4.x architecture. Maybe there is a method that I haven't found yet, but I have searched pretty extensively.

I would like to insert some dynamic, user generated HTML content into an Angular app. This HTML content my also include some known(included in the module declaration) Angular components that should be rendered. Below is some puesdo-app HTML might help me explain:

```
<app-component>

    <!-- standard angular header and router-outlet -->
    <app-header>
        <app-nav>
            <ul>
                <li routerLink="/page-one">First Page</li>
                <li routerLink="/page-two">Second Page</li>
                <li routerLink="/page-three">Third Page</li>
            </ul>
        </app-nav>
    </app-header>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>

    <!--
        the dynamic content would be inserted into the <main> element as HTML with angular <app-... tags
        the content in the HTML content inserted main tag could contain anything
        the angular components within the content should be initalized as normal
    -->
    <main>
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <app-component>
            <p>this component and its content should be initalized when HTML is inserted into main</p>
        </app-component>
        <app-component>
            <app-sub-component>
                angular components here might also contain other angular components
            </app-sub-component>
        </app-component>
        <p>more regular HTML content</p>
    </main>

    <!-- more traditional Angular components could come after -->
    <app-footer></app-footer>

</app-component>
```

I have tried two methods of achieving this, neither of which truly work.

## 1. Using the Dynamic Template/Component pattern with the JIT Compiler.

**TLDR;** It doesn't work with AOT. The AOT is all or nothing.

I've used a dynamic component pattern like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888008/how-can-i-use-create-dynamic-template-to-compile-dynamic-component-with-angular#answer-38888009). This is very simple to implement. Using the JIT Compiler, make a new Component and Module out of the HTML content, and insert an instance of the new component. This works as long as the project is not compiled AOT. Since Angular 4.x the JitCompilerFactory cannot be included in an AOT compiled build. It seems like it might make sense to allow the JIT Complier into AOT compiled builds so known components can get the performance boost, and use the JIT Compiler just for dynamic components. It would be the best of both worlds. BUT, I don't know the inner workings of Angular and I assume there is a good reason not to allow the JIT Compiler's inclusion.

## 2. Using the [Dynamic Component Loader Pattern](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-component-loader.html) pattern

**TLDR;** Can't get an entry point to load the components.

After my issues with the JIT Compiler in an AOT build, I thought I could maybe use the `ComponentFactoryResolver`. Since I'm only using components already declared in the module, I could just create a component in the place of where it should be in the HTML content. This idea is a little crazy, but I thought it might work. My approach would look like this:

1. Insert the dynamic HTML content

   - get dynamic content as HTML
   - don't remove Angular components using the `DomSanatizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml()`,
   - and insert it into the DOM
2. parse the inserted HTML for components

   - using an `{<app-selector-string> : ComponentClass}` json table
   - find all components as DOM Nodes and match them to their corresponding ComponentClass
3. create a view `ViewContainerRef` in the spot I would like to insert the component **(this part is not possible)**
4. using `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()`, create a new instance of the proper component

   - insert it in place of the old element
   - give the component `projectableNodes` that is the content of the old html component
5. give the new component its inputs using a reference to it.

This does not work because dynamically creating a `ViewContainerRef` in *step 3* is not possible.(It may also not be possible to do anything after step 3. IDK. I didn't get that far)

Is there any way to do this? Am I over thinking it?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you build your project?

Comment: See links from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44187413/angular-2-create-viewref-from-markup-injected-into-dynamic-template/44189586#44189586 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40060498/angular-2-1-0-create-child-component-on-the-fly-dynamically/40080290#40080290

Comment: your question is too broad, try to split it into several questions

Comment: @Maximus I dont think its too broad. Basically, James is asking how you can take dynamic html and create a ViewElementRef where certain nodes exist.

Comment: @cgatian You're right. That's what I'm asking. I've done a lot of research on the subject after posting this, and it seems that it is not possible with the current Angular 4.x architecture. No JIT with AOT and no dynamically placed `ViewContainerRefs`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is very possible, actually...

Angular's `ApplicationRef` has an `attachView()` method that will keep track of a new component reference. That component reference can then be inserted anywhere just like a regular component.

Here's a pseudo-code example:

```js
// create a componentRef
const componentFactory = ComponentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(AngularComponent);
const componentRef = componentFactory.create(Injector);

// attach the componentRef to the angular ApplicationRef
ApplicationRef.attachView(componentRef.hostView);

// insert the root element of the new componentRef into any DOM node
const componentRoot: HTMLElement = (componentRef.hostView as EmbeddedViewRef<any>).rootNodes[0];
const node = document.getElementById('insertionPoint'); 
Renderer2.insertBefore(node.parentNode, componentRoot, node);

// don't forget to destroy the component when you're done with it
ApplicationRef.detachView(componentRef.hostView);
componentRef.destroy();
```

Better explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41950786/5648839)

Comment: *Hint* Calling `detachView` and `destroy` right after the injection will result in nothing showing up. See the linked example for how to dispose the component when you are done with it.